# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - apache

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example1.com. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example2.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How to resolve this on apache.

Comment: unix has nothing to do with http cross-domain requests.

Comment: I need help on how to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on apache in mac and linux machines.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Answer (score 0):

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` - to open cors for all domains 
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "http://example2.com"` - to open cors for your domain

More info you can find at http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html.

Comment: I have added as you said, but still, error persists.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example1.com. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.** I'm ran JS on XAMP to parse example1.com (for example). Any help should appreciate.